# CSV export button not added for second table in datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have 3 table in one page. For first table export CSV button added properly. But for second and third table nothing will be add.

Here i am just adding two table code. First table working properly bbut getting issue for second table CSV button

Below is my code

```
var company_table = $('#company_table').DataTable({
    "bProcessing"       : false,
    "bServerSide"       : true,
    "sAjaxSource"       : "<?= route('registration.report')?>",
    "dataSrc"           : "",
    "bAutoWidth"        : false,
    "sPaginationType"   : "full_numbers",
    "aaSorting"         : [ 1,"asc"],
    "bStateSave"        : true,
    "iCookieDuration"   : -1,
    "deferLoading": 0,
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
        [ '10', '25', '50', 'All' ]
    ],
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-3'><'col-sm-6 text-center'><'col-sm-3 text-right'B>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 table-responsive'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'><'col-sm-7'>>",
    "buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'CSV',
            filename: function(){
                var d = new Date();
                var n = d.getHours() + "_" + d.getMinutes() + "_" + d.getSeconds();
                return 'Report1_'+ n;
            },
            attr: {
                class: 'btn',
                id: 'export_table',
            },
        },
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { mData:"date", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"total", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"families",  bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"adult",  bSortable:true, bVisible:true,sClass:"adult_cls"},
        { mData:"senior_citizen", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"Kids", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"Male", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"Female", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
    ],
    "fnPreDrawCallback" : function() { $("div.overlay").css({'display':'flex','top':'60px'}); },
    "fnDrawCallback" : function (oSettings) {
        $("div.overlay").hide();
        var api = this.api(), data;
       
    },
    "fnStateLoadParams" : function (oSettings, oData) {
    
        $('#city').val(oData.city).trigger('change');
        $('#state').val(oData.state).trigger('change'); 
       
        
    },
    "fnStateSaveParams": function (oSettings, oData) {
     
        oData.city = $('#city').val();
        oData.state = $('#state').val(); 
       
    },
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
     
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        
        aoData.push({ "name": "city", "value": city });
        aoData.push({ "name": "state", "value": state });
        server_params = aoData;
    },
});

var company_table1 = $('#company_table2').DataTable({
    "bProcessing"       : false,
    "bServerSide"       : true,
    "sAjaxSource"       : "<?= route('registration.report_index2')?>",
    "dataSrc"           : "",
    "bAutoWidth"        : false,
    "sPaginationType"   : "full_numbers",
    "aaSorting"         : [ 1,"asc"],
    "bStateSave"        : true,
    "iCookieDuration"   : -1,
    // "dom"               : 'Bfrtip',
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
        [ '10', '25', '50', 'All' ]
    ],
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-3'><'col-sm-6 text-center'><'col-sm-3 text-right'>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 table-responsive'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'><'col-sm-7'>>",
    "buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'CSV',
            filename: function(){
                var d = new Date();
                var n = d.getHours() + "_" + d.getMinutes() + "_" + d.getSeconds();
                return 'Report2_'+ n;
            },
            attr: {
                class: 'btn',
                id: 'export_table_new2',
            },
        },
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { mData:"date", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"total", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"families",  bSortable:true, bVisible:true,},
        { mData:"slots",  bSortable:true, bVisible:true,
            mRender: function(v, t, o) {
                var slot = o['slots'];
                var slot= slot.split('\n');
                var act_html = "";
                $.each(slot, function(index, value) { 
           act_html += value+"<br>";
        });
        return act_html;
            }
        },
        { mData:"train_slots", bSortable:true, bVisible:true,
            mRender: function(v, t, o) {
                var slot = o['train_slots'];
                var slot= slot.split('\n');
                var act_html = "";
                $.each(slot, function(index, value) { 
           act_html += value+"<br>";
        });
        return act_html;
            }
        },
       
    ],
    "fnPreDrawCallback" : function() { $("div.overlay").css({'display':'flex','top':'60px'}); },
    "fnDrawCallback" : function (oSettings) {
        $("div.overlay").hide();
        var api = this.api(), data;
        
       
    },
    "fnStateLoadParams" : function (oSettings, oData) {
        $('#city').val(oData.city).trigger('change');
        $('#state').val(oData.state).trigger('change'); 
    },
    "fnStateSaveParams": function (oSettings, oData) {
        oData.city = $('#city').val();
        oData.state = $('#state').val(); 
       
    },
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        
        
        aoData.push({ "name": "city", "value": city });
        aoData.push({ "name": "state", "value": state });
        
        server_params = aoData;
    },
});
```

If anyone have idea what is exact wrong in that then please let me know

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: In sDom i forgot add B. Issue has been resolved.